# If is greater than previous cell at different location

Tags: excel, vba

I have to check, if the value in cell "C" is greater than 0, but less than value in PREVIOUS cell "E"., for example, checking, if the value at cell "3C" is greater than 0, but less than value in cell "2E". I have put in RGB for it to color the error included cell red. I'm also using UserForms for input.

This is my code in Excel VBA:

```
    X = Cells(j, "C").Value 
    d = Cells(j, "E").Value
    c = Cells(j, "E-1").Value
    If X >= c And X < 0 Or X < 0 Or X >= c Then
            Cells(j, "C").Interior.Color = 255
            UserForm1.inpBox.Value = j
            UserForm1.Label1.Caption = (j & ". Row has an error!")
            UserForm1.Show
            Cells(j, "C") = UserForm1.inpBox.Value
            Cells(j, "C").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End If
```

I know that there is a mistake in here, but I can't figure out, what to put in it's place for it to work:

```
    X = Cells(j, "C").Value 
    d = Cells(j, "E").Value
    c = Cells(j, "E-1").Value
    If X >= c And X < 0 Or X < 0 Or X >= c Then
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Range.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) method:

```
c = Cells(j, "E").Offset(0, -1).Value  ' addresses "previous" column
c = Cells(j, "E").Offset(-1, 0).Value  ' addresses "previous" row
```

Comment: I wrote this and it seems to work: `c = Cells(j - 1, "E").Value` What do you think about this version?

Comment: This will work as well when you provide numeric row and column. Note that in your "not working" example you try to address previous *column* `"E-1"`, whereas in you comment you subtract one from the *row*. `Offset` method will work if you use named ranges or provide columns as letters. Both are good.

Comment: Thanks you a lot! :)